# T-SQL pathname manipulation

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

OK so I'm a bit rusty on parts of T-SQL such as string manipulation
I got a string in a field called [path] the value of the field could look like

```
'foo\Branches\Bar\Baz\Helpers\FileNotFoundResult.cs'
```

I need to update the field (for all records) so that the result will be

```
'Branches\Bar\Baz\Helpers\FileNotFoundResult.cs'
```

that is strip of anything before the first '\' and the '\'

so I'd appricate if any one could help me fill in the "blanks"

```
UPDATE SourceFiles
   SET Path = <blanks>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
UPDATE SourceFiles
    SET Path = SUBSTRING(Path,CHARINDEX('\',Path)+1,8000)
```

(Assuming your Path column isn't a varchar(max))

If your path column might not contain a backslash at all, you might want:

```
UPDATE SourceFiles
    SET Path = CASE
                   WHEN CHARINDEX('\',Path) = 0 THEN Path
                   ELSE SUBSTRING(Path,CHARINDEX('\',Path)+1,8000)
               END
```